# nuxt services not receiving cookies from service to service using Express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, nuxt.js

I have 3 different services.

1. Front End, what you see from the browser
2. An auth service running on port 3001
3. An admin service running on port 3002

I set a cookie on the auth service if you correctly authenticate

```
res.cookie('tmC', JSON.stringify(cookieObj), {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      })
```

On the frontend in my nuxt config I have

```
axios: {
    // baseUrl: process.env.NUXT_ENV_API_URL
    credentials: true,
    init(axios) {
      axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    },
  },
```

In my services I have cors setup as so

```
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'POST'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

The origin must be 3000 (front end, as this is where all requests originate. No matter how hard I fight this, the cookies are always null. If I use postman, I see the cookies just fine. Any ideas?